# Spring boot not serving Single page index.html when SSL is configured

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, ssl, spring-boot

I have spring boot single page web application using angular js, bootstrap for the front end and rest API for the back-end and both front-end and back-end runs on embedded tomcat container of spring boot. I am using spring boot 1.2.7 version

Following code sample shows how I am bootstrap this spring boot application

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "sg.abc.test.api.config", Constant.BASE_PACKAGE, sg.abc.c4s.util.Constant.BASE_PACKAGE })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:jdbc.properties")
})
public class TestApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestApp.class);

    @Autowired
    InternalSettingService internalSettingService;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application.headless(true);
        return application.sources(TestApp.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper mapper() {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        return mapper;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(EmenuApp.class);
            builder.headless(false);


            context = builder.run(new String[] {});
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Butterfly eMenu Application already running.");
        }
    }
```

This system works without ssl configuration. However when I configure spring boot to have ssl, I am only able to access the rest api, but the web app is not getting loaded into the browser.

Could anybody advice me what could be the reason behind this wired behavior. If u require further explanations please put a comment below, I will provide more details.

It is not self signed certificate.

I got the certificate from godaddy

This is how I configured it

```
server.ssl.key-store=data/test.keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password=test123
server.ssl.key-password=test123
```

with this configuration, rest api works fine and responds to https api calls, only the web application is not responding , this is what I see in the browser

[image]

Comment: how did you configure the spring ssl. Is it self signed? please provide the `application.properties" if you did it there. What error did you get?

Comment: Also please define what happens precisely. If you make a request to index.html, what do you get back as a response (status code, body, etc.)?

Comment: @MinjunYu I have updated the question

Comment: @JBNizet, I get the same response as in the image if I specifically mention the index.html

Comment: Hey  Kltis , did it work for you ? I am also facing similar issue

Comment: right-click on the page select inspect (On Chrome), then go to the console, it will show what is the error message. In my case, I had CSS and JS files from external resources which are not SSL secured.